# Lua Script - run again

Tags: c++, c, lua

I have Lua embeded in my C/C++ app. If I run script with

```
lua_pcall( luaState, 0, LUA_MULTRET, 0 );
```

for the first time, all is OK (return 0). But I need to run script again after some time. Calling same function again, script is not executed and retun value is 2. How can I run it again without reload everything again from file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Push it twice on the stack or store it as a global variable.